# Windows - Mount a directory to another directory as R/O

Tags: windows, mount, read-only

I know I can do the equivalent to "mount a directory to another directory" in Windows with

```
mklink /j mountpoint source
```

This isn't really "mounting", though, it's only a symbolic link in NTFS.

Now I want to do that as read-only, i.e., programs cannot modify the content via `mountpoint\`, but they can via `source\`. The Unix equivalent is

```
mount -o ro,bind source mountpoint
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in 2 steps:

1. Use MKlink, but with /D switch, which is create hardlink instead junction
2. Set the security properties for the newly created hardlink (deny write, execute etc)

If you did well, you can't do anything except read from the hardlink, but
do everything from the original mount point.